# Write xml cofiguration file and C# parser for ado.net query 

Tags: c#, xml, configuration, ado.net

I want to write an XML configuration file that contains query to the same db, only query to view. The "query node" must have the filters parameter.

How can I write this XML file and the C# Parser, and QueryBuilder classes.

I want some thing like this:

```
<Query Name="Application Approval by Month" src="APPLICATION_APPROVAL_COUNT_BY_MONTH">
    <Filters>         
        <Filter Type="DropDownList" ID="ddlYears"  DataType="DateTime">
            <Fill Mode="AutoIncrement" Src="AppMonth" Step="1" Min="2005" Max="2010"> 
            </Fill>
            <Operator Type="Between">   
            </Operator>
        </Filter>
    </Filters>
</Query>
```

C# code :

```
public class QueryBuilder {

    public QueryBuilder(string viewName)
    {
        _query = "select * from " + viewName;
    }

    public void AddFilter(string operator, string name, string val)
    {
        _query = String.Format("{0} {1}{2}'{3}' ", _query, name, operator,val);
    }

    public DataTable ExcecuteQuery()
    {
        DataTable dt;
        // ado.net action

        return dt;
    }
}
```

This is for dinamycly reports include chart.

I use the filters for build filter toolbox.

These is for a better development, when I have to add a new report or chart ( in the XML I have and the part that build the report or chart ) I have to add the view  edit only the XML from adimin.

Lets explain the XML:

- Tag query attribute src is the name of view.
- Tag filter have too function : 1 get the control to add in the toolbox, 2 get the data source for these control if exist in these case the src.
- Tag operator is the sql filter operator.

Any ideas or example?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no idea what you are asking, can you provide a better explanation and/or an example of what you need?

Comment: @Binary, Seems like he wants an xml-file, something like this i imagine `<query filter="">select * from xx</quert>` and he wants a parser + query builder for that.

Comment: *@haroldis-nio:* I fixed the formatting of your XML example. You need to indent pre-formatted stuff by 4 spaces so that it shows up OK.

Comment: This seems to have very little to do with ADO.NET. It rather seems like you want a configuration file that allows you to generate a form for setting a particular query's (`APPLICATION_APPROVAL_COUNT_BY_MONTH`) parameters. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Before anyone can counsel you on your XML schema, you'll have to explain what *exactly* you want to do.

Comment: IMHO, you're asking for SQL injection attacks against this software.

Comment: In my understanding, you want to give the name of the `view` and its filter parameters in the config file and then get the data from the config file and execute the view and get the results. If correct, you have to check for the `SQL-Injection` attacks and then you have to use parameters instead of appending values to query as such. Further you can refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056290/executing-t-sql-view-from-ado-net